# How to Determine Java Heap Size On Application Startup

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I have a java desktop application that supports viewing very large amounts of data at a time. In order to support this, I start the application with high `-Xms -Xmx` settings. For example,

```
-Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

The problem I run into is that depending on the client machine and current usage, the Java virtual machine can't always start up with such high settings. The solution is to lower the size.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? How did you solve it? Is there a way to predetermine good `-Xms` and `-Xmx` sizes? Or is there a way to specify size within the application and not at start up?

Comment: The only way to specify the size at runtime is to have it start another JVM with the desired maximum heap size.

Comment: Your application either *does* or *doesn't* need that much memory. If it doesn't, then lower the limits; if it does, then buy more RAM to be able to run it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that's not really true. Sometimes an algorithm can run more efficiently with more RAM, but still get the work done with a small memory footprint. Think sorting: you can do it very efficiently if you can do it all in memory, but you can fall back to using disk space if necessary.

Comment: @chiastic-security Yes, I know that, but I have a feeling that OP's application is not designed that way.

Comment: can you give more information about the data you are loading and how you are actually loading it? It may help give another approach to achieve your task with less memory usage.

Comment: Sure. The application supports opening charts in multiple views at a time. There can be a number of views open at a time and the charts can grow in size depending on how fast the samples come in. Most users won't open views that consume lots of memory so a low memory setting is fine for most users. However, I need to set -Xms and -Xmx high otherwise the application won't work at all for users who do view memory intensive charts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't determine it in your Java code, because it's too late by then: it's a property of the JVM, which has already been fired up.

You'd need to do something OS-specific to determine the available memory and start the JVM with appropriate parameters. For instance, on Linux, you could start your application with a `bash` script, which would start by examining `/proc/meminfo` to determine system config, and then fire up the Java program, setting the heap size accordingly.

Comment: This answer makes sense and would work. It is unfortunate there is no way to change this while running.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script or batch script to determine the server RAM capacity and based on that you can pass in the heap size parameter during the JVM start up.